# Inflate zlib compressed data

Tags: javascript, zlib, compression

I have a ArrayBuffer of data that was compressed using the C++ version of zlibs deflate (with default values). As there is no server i need to inflate this data now in the client. I have done this with the default inflate options in C++ and it worked without problems. Now in the browser i have tested various libraries, neither of them worked, here are a few exempts:

- zLib.js: invalid BTYPE 3
- pako.js: invalid stored block length
- JSinflate: generally failed

So i wonder is there an easy way to get my ArrayBuffer with deflate data inflated? I tried creating a blob and an object url with application/zlib and then an ajax request with accepts: application/octet-stream but then i get the zlib input again, without decompression.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem using emscripten

I have converted inflate.c from zlib directly with a handler function that makes wrapping a bit easier to javascript using emscripten and now the decompression works perfectly.